# __init__() missing 4 required positional arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created this code but i keep getting the error: TypeError: **init**() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'x', 'y', 'r', and and 'color'. Any idea? pls

This is my code below:

```
import math
    
    class objeto:
        def __init__(self,x, y, r, color):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.r = r
            self.color = color
            
        def colicionEntre(self,pelota):
            distancia = math.sqrt(pow(self.x-pelota.x,2)+pow(self.y-pelota.y,2))
            radios = self.r + pelota.r
            cad = "La pelota " + self.color + " y la pelota " + pelota.color
            if(distancia<radios):
                cad = cad + " si colicionan"
            else:
                cad = cad + " no colicionan"
            return cad
    
        def procesarLista(self,listaPelotas):
            for i in range(len(listaPelotas)):
                for x in range(i,len(listaPelotas)):
                    if(listaPelotas[i]!=listaPelotas[x]):
                        print(listaPelotas[i].colicionEntre(listaPelotas[x]))
                        
    pelota = objeto(3,4,2,"Amarilla")
    pelota2 = objeto(5,5,1,"Verde")
    pelota3 = objeto(2,2,1,"Roja")
    pelota4 = objeto(1,1,1,"Azul")
    lista = [pelota,pelota2,pelota3,pelota4]
    objetoObj = objeto()
    objetoObj.procesarLista(lista)
```

Comment: `objetoObj = objeto()` is creating an object of the class, however your  `__init__()` requires 4 elements, and you have provided none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class objeto:
    def __init__(self,x, y, r, color):
```

Your class takes 4 arguments but when you call it:

```
objetoObj = objeto()
```

you are not giving it any arguments. Try putting arguments in (they may be `None`)

Answer (score 1):

The core issue for your error is that you've tried to create an object which requires 4 positional arguments, which you have not provided.

```
objetoObj = objeto()
```

Judging by your code, and what you seem to be intending to achieve, you should move the function `procesarLista` **outside** of your class.

Once you've done this, you can pass your list of objects to your function, nothing to remove `self` and your function will run as you have written it.

```
import math
    
class objeto:
    def __init__(self,x, y, r, color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.r = r
        self.color = color
        
    def colicionEntre(self,pelota):
        distancia = math.sqrt(pow(self.x-pelota.x,2)+pow(self.y-pelota.y,2))
        radios = self.r + pelota.r
        cad = "La pelota " + self.color + " y la pelota " + pelota.color
        if(distancia<radios):
            cad = cad + " si colicionan"
        else:
            cad = cad + " no colicionan"
        return cad

def procesarLista(listaPelotas):
    for i in range(len(listaPelotas)):
        for x in range(i,len(listaPelotas)):
            if(listaPelotas[i]!=listaPelotas[x]):
                print(listaPelotas[i].colicionEntre(listaPelotas[x]))
                    
pelota = objeto(3,4,2,"Amarilla")
pelota2 = objeto(5,5,1,"Verde")
pelota3 = objeto(2,2,1,"Roja")
pelota4 = objeto(1,1,1,"Azul")
lista = [pelota,pelota2,pelota3,pelota4]

procesarLista(lista)
```

Output

---

```
La pelota Amarilla y la pelota Verde si colicionan
La pelota Amarilla y la pelota Roja si colicionan
La pelota Amarilla y la pelota Azul no colicionan
La pelota Verde y la pelota Roja no colicionan
La pelota Verde y la pelota Azul no colicionan
La pelota Roja y la pelota Azul si colicionan
>>>
```

Comment: The other option would be to define procesarLista as a static method and then invoke it with objecto.procesarList(lista).   Note that static methods do not have a self argument.  static methods are created by decorating them with  @staticmethod

Comment: @LhasaDad Given the OP's intentions, handling multiple objects. I believe you would be better off not creating a new object just to handle the ones you've already created. Maybe even write a function and pass it a list of objects to process.

Comment: There was an typo in my first response. i said objecto when I ment to say objeto,  the class name.  objeto.procesarLista(xxxx) would invoke the static method without ever creating an object.  It will behave the same way as what you suggest but it namespaces the method to being associated with the class.   Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the main problem noted by others about your object, you can simplify your procesarLista() method and get rid of the conditional statement as follows:

```
def procesarLista(self, listaPelotas):
    for i in range(len(listaPelotas)):
        for x in range(i+1, len(listaPelotas)):
                print(listaPelotas[i].colicionEntre(listaPelotas[x]))

#output:
La pelota Amarilla y la pelota Verde si colicionan
La pelota Amarilla y la pelota Roja si colicionan
La pelota Amarilla y la pelota Azul no colicionan
La pelota Verde y la pelota Roja no colicionan
La pelota Verde y la pelota Azul no colicionan
La pelota Roja y la pelota Azul si colicionan
```

Comment: This is not answering  the original question.  While true its not answering the question asked.

Comment: @LhasaDad that’s why I started my answer acknowledging that others had addressed the main problem. This was an additional issue with the code that others had not brought up, so I thought it would be helpful. In fact, OP did find it helpful and upvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer for causing this issue is because that objetoObj = objeto() returned a missing argument error since you didn't pass the 4 arguments into the object you are trying to build.

However, You did create 4 objects that contained those neccessary arugments. In my view, you just wanted to apply the function 'procesarLista(listaPelotas) which can process the list you've built. The code snippet you've built confused you a little bit as you created a function to process a list of objects within a single object.

A quick solution for addressing this issue is that you could add a notation: @staticmethod at the top of the function procesarLista(listaPelotas) as the following:

```
{
import math

class objeto:  

def __init__(self,x, y, r, color):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.r = r
    self.color = color

def colicionEntre(self,pelota):
    distancia = math.sqrt(pow(self.x-pelota.x,2)+pow(self.y-pelota.y,2))
    radios = self.r + pelota.r
    cad = "La pelota " + self.color + " y la pelota " + pelota.color
    if(distancia<radios):
        cad = cad + " si colicionan"
    else:
        cad = cad + " no colicionan"
    return cad

@staticmethod
def procesarLista(listaPelotas):
    for i in range(len(listaPelotas)):
        for x in range(i,len(listaPelotas)):
            if(listaPelotas[i]!=listaPelotas[x]):
                print(listaPelotas[i].colicionEntre(listaPelotas[x]))
```

}

```
pelota = objeto(3,4,2,"Amarilla")
pelota2 = objeto(5,5,1,"Verde")
pelota3 = objeto(2,2,1,"Roja")
pelota4 = objeto(1,1,1,"Azul")
```

Now that you've created the staticmethod, we can call it explicitely like this:

```
objeto.procesarLista(lista)  
La pelota Amarilla y la pelota Verde si colicionan  
La pelota Amarilla y la pelota Roja si colicionan  
La pelota Amarilla y la pelota Azul no colicionan  
La pelota Verde y la pelota Roja no colicionan  
La pelota Verde y la pelota Azul no colicionan  
La pelota Roja y la pelota Azul si colicionan
```